# Android processing a video to CMYK

Tags: android, ffmpeg, frame, video-processing, cmyk

I am working on a project and in that project I need to be able to:

1. get a frame of a video
2. change it to a CMYK
3. try to render that frame

Do you guys have any suggestions?

To get the frames I think I can use ffmpeg.
I think the person that wrote
[Android processing a video, YCrCb frames to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334136/android-processing-a-video-ycrcb-frames-to-video)
can help me but I'm open to any suggestions.

I appreciate all the help I can get, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to convert YUV to RGB, the remaining problem is RGB to CMYK. This can be very simple (C = 1 - R, M = 1 - G, Y = 1 - B) or very complex (3D LUT implementing a complex gamut mapping based on tone curves and ink coverages, etc.). You can assume video has standard Rec.709 gamma but you'll need to better define what kind of CMYK you're looking for and if they are linear or some other mapping.